# How to use dynamically added toolstripmenuitem

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a tool strip item that contains bookmarks and each bookmark should go to the page. How do make each button work?.

```
    For Each b In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Bookmarks").GetFiles
        BookmarksToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(b.Name)
    Next
```

Comment: you are going to need to hook each one up to a click event (Addhandler) for starters.

Comment: The addhandler wants an object but the object hasn't been made yet.

Comment: The Add() method returns it.

Comment: 'AddHandler' or 'RemoveHandler' statement event operand must be a dot-qualified expression or a simple name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a too [ToolStripMenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx), then add handlers and put it to your toolstripmenu object instead of adding to toolstripmenu a string object.

```
For Each b In New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("Bookmarks").GetFiles
    Dim menuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem(b.Name)
    'Add any handlers here

    'Click handler to your menuItem.
    AddHandler menuItem.Click, AddressOf menuItem_Click 'CLICK EVENT HANDLER ALSO UNIQUE

    'Add menuItem to ToolStripMenu
    BookmarksToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(menuItem)
Next


Private Sub menuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'CODE TO HANDLE CLICK EVENT
End Sub
```

If you don't know how to dynamicaly add handlers then take a look at [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5041/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-VB-NET).